# How to set the default document reader in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: command-line, 16.04, default-programs, okular

A long time ago it was possible to set default applications through the command line in the file `~/.local/share/applications/defaults.list`. But this file is no longer around.

How could I set Okular as the default document reader in Ubuntu 16.04 using the command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default applications seem to be set globally in the `/usr/share/applications/defaults.list` as association pairs between application and file. User specific file associations can be set in the file `~/.local/share/applications/defaults.list`. This file may not exist - perhaps after a fresh Ubuntu install - but can be created by the user.

I now use a script like the one below to associate applications to file types. In this example Okular is associated with all document types (replacing Evince).

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -e ~/.local/share/applications/defaults.list ]
then
    echo "The file exists"
    sed 's/evince/okular/' ~/.local/share/applications/defaults.list > ~/.local/share/applications/defaults.list
else
    echo "The file does not exist"
    sed 's/evince/okular/' /usr/share/applications/defaults.list > ~/.local/share/applications/defaults.list
fi
```

Comment: This works for me. `~/.local/share/applications/defaults.list` was exist but empty other than the header on the first line. What I did was to copy the line from `/usr/share/applications/defaults.list` which define `application/pdf` and make change so `okular.desktop` is the first option.

Answer (score 10):

In my knowledge you can set a default app through xdg-mime.

```
xdg-mime default okular.desktop application/pdf
```

To check if it worked:

```
xdg-mime query default application/pdf
```

Comment: After running this, PDF documents are still being opened by Evince. Anything else I should do?

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me:

`xdg-mime default okularApplication_pdf.desktop application/pdf`

I used Alex's previous answer (sorry, I could not comment it...) and updated it.

The line:

`xdg-mime query default application/pdf`
works well.

Now, all my pdfs are opened with Okular by default.
Thank you, Alex!

Comment: You can suggest an edit if you want to update an answer: https://askubuntu.com/posts/805577/edit

Comment: Thank you, muru! I didn't know. I will do that next time.